# How to verify if money was sent

Tags: transactions

My friend was supposed to send me $800 last night. He says he sent itAs that make up ever see this as he sucked bitcoin but it doesn’t show where it was sent. And my account which is new and doesn’t show anything in it. It’s just someone I can speak with to verify whether this occurred or not?

Comment: Hi @Rob martin, what wallet software are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an address or transaction id, you can look that up on a block explorer like blockchain.info. Also, you may have to wait for several confirmations (depending on your wallet) before your wallet software will count it towards your balance (each confirmation takes about 10 minutes on average).